Clarification on the dot notation in formulas
I am going through the book "Computational Complexity Theory" (Rudich, Wigderson). On Page 22, the following appears:

That is, $A \in \mathbf{NP}$ if there exists an integer $k$ and a polynomial time relation $R$, such that
$$x \in A \Leftrightarrow \exists y . |y| < |x|^k . R(x, y).$$
The existentially quantified $y$ is a "guess", which $R$ "checks," and is often called a succinct or short certificate, witness, or proof.

My question is how exactly do I interpret the above formula using parentheses (instead of the dots)? Thanks in advance!

There are many different notations for applying quantifiers. How about $(\exists y)(|y| < |x|^k \land R(x, y))$? How would you use parentheses for other formulas?

@DavidK, That is the only interpretation that made sense to me too. But how exactly did you interpret the second dot as $\land$? Thanks.

@MathIdiot That's the meaning of a bounded existential quantifier.

Once a usual element of notation, dot has long faded away from the formal language of logic. The following excerpt that describes its twofold use is from the second edition of Principia Mathematica by Alfred N. Whitehead and Bertrand Russell:

It seems the editors have opted for it because of its plainness and employed both uses of the dot, as to bracket off expressions and a symbol for conjunction ("logical product"). Hence, in the contemporary standard notation, the expression must read
$$x\in A \Leftrightarrow\exists y(|y| < |x|^k\wedge R(x, y))$$
